How to Load User Profile in Angular Application Using Keycloak Token
I am developing an Angular application that utilizes Keycloak for authentication. I have successfully implemented the authentication process and able to get access token. Now, I need to load the user profile using this token.
I have looked into Keycloak-Angular's documentation, but it seems to focus on handling authentication using its own mechanisms, whereas I obtained the token through other means.
However, I'm unsure about how to proceed with loading the user profile using the token s. Can anyone provide guidance on how to achieve this?
